# Why does this just stop after running a function, and why does this variable not go up?

Tags: python-3.x

```
deathcounter, r, n, deaths=0, 0, 0, 0
def gamestart():
    print("Enter the cheese world?")
    print("(1) Yes (2) No")
    n=int(input(""))
def gameover():
    print("GAME OVER")
    deathcounter=deaths+1
    n=0
    r=0
    gamestart()
print("Deaths :", deathcounter)
gamestart()
if n == 1:
    print("You enter the cheese world. It's full of cheese.")
    print("(1) Eat the cheese (2) Banish the cheese")
    r=int(input(""))
if n == 2:
    print("You reject the cheese world. What is the point anymore.")
    gameover()
if r == 1:
    print("You eat the cheese. You die from an artery blockage.")
    gameover()
if r == 2:
    print("You attempt to banish the cheese. The cheese's power is incomprehensible to you, and you lose your mind.")
    gameover()
```

I don't get why this prints `gamestart()` and then just stops, and why `deathcounter` doesn't go up after running `gameover()`.

I just started programming so criticism is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables `deathcounter`, `n` and `r` inside functions `gamestart` and `gameover` are local to those function, they are not same as variables you defined in the first line. So, changes made to any of those variables inside the `gamestart` and `gameover` won't reflect to the global variables. If you want changes to be reflected in global scope, then you should use `global` keyword.

You can read about global variables here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/

Your code after using `global` keyword:

```
deathcounter, r, n, deaths=0, 0, 0, 0

def gamestart():
    global n
    print("Enter the cheese world?")
    print("(1) Yes (2) No")
    n=int(input(""))

def gameover():
    global n, r, deathcounter
    print("GAME OVER")
    deathcounter=deaths+1
    n=0
    r=0
    gamestart()

print("Deaths :", deathcounter)
gamestart()
if n == 1:
    print("You enter the cheese world. It's full of cheese.")
    print("(1) Eat the cheese (2) Banish the cheese")
    r=int(input(""))
if n == 2:
    print("You reject the cheese world. What is the point anymore.")
    gameover()
if r == 1:
    print("You eat the cheese. You die from an artery blockage.")
    gameover()
if r == 2:
    print("You attempt to banish the cheese. The cheese's power is incomprehensible to you, and you lose your mind.")
    gameover()
```

Comment: worked, but stops printing the text after giving n a second time. +1

Comment: @jorma yeah, there are some logical errors in the program. You can spot those problems in a few minutes. I did not mention those problems in my answer, because I was only answering your question

Comment: @jorma hint: use a while loop

Answer (score 0):

you need to claim those variables as global inside functions.

e.g.

```
global n
# then
n=int(input(""))
```

Comment: Helped, but stops after giving `n` a second time.